# How to get audit revisions of Many To Many joined table using Envers audit query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have two domains (User, Role). Both are in many to many relationship. hibernate auto generated 3 tables (User, Role, UserRole).

I have integrated hibernate envers for auditing purpose. I am able get the revisions from User & Role tables. How can I get audit revisions from UserRole audit table.

Here, we didnt create UserRole domain. Based on the many to many relationship, UserRole table automatically created. So there is no domain (UserRole) to get audit revisions from UserRole audit table user audit query.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `UserRole` is a join-table, you would want to access the changes to that association from the owning side of that many-to-many relationship.  I'm going to assume for sake of example that `User` is the owner of the association; so you would access those similar to the following:

```
User user = auditReader.find( User.class, userId, revisionNumber );
List<UserRole> userRoles = user.getUserRoles();
```

The above would provide you all the `UserRole` entities in the join-table at `revisionNumber` for `User` with the specified identifier value of `userId`.